# How to type a proper Hawaiʻian ʻokina

Tags: typography

I'm writing a paper on Hawaiian, and I wonder what the proper way of writing an [ʻokina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOkina) is in LaTeX. I believe it is U+02BB in Unicode (correct me if I'm wrong). For now, I have been replacing it by typing a grave accent ` in LaTeX, but I believe it yields U+2018, so it's similar, but not the same glyph.

Thanks!

Comment: it depends on the font you are using, in classic tex the fonts only have 127 or 256 characters so do not have a separate glyph for this in the common text fonts if you use lulatex or xelatex you could type U+02BB directly if your opentype font has the character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be font-dependent. With `pdflatex` one can scale a backquote and raise it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar,graphicx}
%\usepackage{libertine}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\okina}{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`A-\height}{%
    \scalebox{0.8}{`}%
  }%
}
\newunicodechar{ʻ}{\okina}

\begin{document}

``ʻ\=Olelo Hawaiʻi''

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `libertine` enabled:

[image]

Compare with XeLaTeX and Libertinus Serif

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}

``ʻ\=Olelo Hawaiʻi''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works nicely. Since the Unicode description is Modifier letter turned comma, I originally tried to turn a comma and raise it, but I failed. Would this approach yield the same result if successful?

Comment: @Lundgren8 In most fonts a comma is a rotated version of the left quote.

Comment: It's a good question, though, for the case when the comma isn't a rotated left quote; cf. Wikipedia, "Additionally, the left single quotation mark is represented in some typefaces by a mirrored "9" glyph, rather than a "6", which is unsuitable for the ʻokina."

Comment: @AnnieCarter Nothing would be better than a properly designed glyph. Different fonts would need different treatment.